# Stiffness and stability - proof of order stages

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've got this theorem in my book which say:

"The order of a Runge–Kutta method with $s$ stages cannot exceed
$2s$"

Proof: Assume that $p ≥ 2s + 1$. The corresponding quadrature formula
\begin{equation}\int_{t_m}^{t_{m+1}} f(t) dt \approx h\sum_{i=1}^{s} b_if(t_m+c_i h) \end{equation}
is then exact for all polynomials of degree ≤ 2s: From the “bushy” trees we obtain the order conditions
\begin{equation}\sum_{i=1}^s b_ic_i^{l-1}=\frac{1}{l} \end{equation}
for $l=1,...,2s+1$
This implying
\begin{equation}\int_{t_m}^{t_{m+1}}(t-t_m)^{l-1}dt=\frac{1}{l}h^l=h\sum_{i=1}^s b_i(c_ih)^{l-1}=\frac{1}{l}h^l \end{equation}
for $l=1,...,2s+1$
Choose
\begin{equation}f(t)=\prod_{i=1}^s(t-t_m-c_ih)^2 \end{equation}
Then $\int_{t_m}^{t_{m+1}}f(t) dt >0$, but $h\sum_{i=1}^s b_if(t_m+c_ih)=0$ which is a contradiciton!

--

I can't figure it out, so can anyone here clearify it for me? Thanks in advance.

Update: Why do we choose
\begin{equation} f(t)=\prod_{i=1}^s(t-t_m-c_ih)^2 \end{equation}
and why the integral

\begin{equation} \int_{t_m}^{t_{m+1}}(t-t_m)^{l-1}dt \end{equation}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a proof by contradiction, so they aim to construct a polynomial of degree $\leq 2s$ for which the quadrature formula is not exact.

The function $f$ chosen here is clearly a polynomial of degree $2s$ (the highest power of $t$ is $2s$), and it has double zeros at each $t = t_m + c_i h$, $i=1,2,\dots,s$. Therefore, the quadrature formula yields $0$ for this polynomial, and it remains to show that the integral of $f$ over $(t_m,t_{m+1})$ is not zero.

This is obvious since $f$, as a product of squares, is a non-negative function, and it's not the zero function. Therefore, the integral of $f$ over $(t_m,t_{m+1})$ must be positive.

I don't really see why we need the integrals of $(t-t_m)^{\ell-1}$, but I guess the author's idea could be that by expanding $f$ we can obtain a sum of powers of $t-t_m$, and then the integral of $f$ can be written as a sum of integrals of $(t-t_m)^{\ell-1}$, each of which is positive.